# Smallest offset so that the Rips complex is always a subcomplex of the Cech complex.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Let $X$ be a finite set of points in $\mathbb R^n$.

For $\epsilon >0$, let $\mathcal R_\epsilon (X)$ and $\mathcal C_\epsilon (X)$ be the Rips and Cech complexes on $X$, respectively.

It's [well-known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361882/how-much-smaller-is-the-%C4%8Cech-complex-than-the-vietoris-rips-complex#:%7E:text=The%20%C4%8Cech%20complex%20is%20a,balls%20centered%20on%20the%20points.) the Cech complex is always a subcomplex of the Rips complex, but when is the Rips complex a subcomplex of the Cech complex?

In other words, what is the smallest $\delta > 0$ (as a function of $n$) such that $\mathcal C_\delta (X)$ is a subcomplex of $\mathcal R_\epsilon (X)$ for all $\epsilon >0$?

(This appears as a bonus problem in [Problem Set 1](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/nanda/cat/2021CatEx1.pdf) of Vidit Nanda's Computational Algebraic Topology course)

Well, for the Rips complex to be a subcomplex we would need that wherever a subset of $k$ points are pairwise at most $\epsilon$ distance apart from each other, the balls of radius $\delta$ around those points have nonempty intersection.

Nanda specifies in the question that $\delta$ is a function of $n$, which I don't quite understand the relevance of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De Silva and Ghrist showed in ["Coverage in sensor networks via persistent homology"](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Eghrist/preprints/persistent.pdf) (theorem 2.5) that if $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, then $$\mathcal{R}_{\epsilon'}(X) \subseteq \mathcal{C}_\epsilon(X) \subseteq \mathcal{R}_\epsilon(X)$$ whenever $\epsilon \geq \epsilon' \sqrt{\frac{2n}{n+1}}$, and that this constant is optimal in general (in fact, attained by points on a regular $n$-simplex).